# Cannot insert equivalent plain text of diacritic text in mysql using DBI in perl

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a column which is primary key for my table, which can have diacritic or normal text.

I have these 2 values:

```
Håbo and Habo
```

I want to insert these two column values in my table, but i am getting error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry 'Habo' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

As i check Håbo is already inserted and it is treating both values same so primary key violation.

My code:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass)
            or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'}=1;
$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');
my $sql = sprintf "INSERT INTO search_term values(%s, %s)", $dbh->quote($search_term), "Data";
```

My table description

```
mysql> desc search_term;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| search        | varchar(200) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| site          | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How can i make MySQL treat both values as different and insert them?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the create table or describe output.

Comment: @FreudianSlip: I have made edit and posted the desc of my table

Comment: As a side note, prefer bind parameters over using quote.  It's both faster and more secure.  Also always specify the columns in the INSERT, otherwise you're relying on the details of the table ordering which could change, and its harder to understand.  `$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO search_term (search, site) VALUES(?, ?)"); $sth->execute($search, "Data");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MySQL ["helpfully" converts Unicode into their "equivalent" ASCII](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html) using something called [Unicode Collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm).  Like a lot of "convenience" features in MySQL, this would be much handier if it told you.  I cannot put enough "quotes" around those "words".

Fortunately the fix is pretty simple, but non obvious.  First, [change the character set of your tables to UTF8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) so text is stored in utf8.  Then [change the collation to utf8_bin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-binary-collations.html) so comparisons will be done exactly.  I'm not 100% sure utf8_bin is 100% the right thing, but it works.

```
ALTER TABLE search_term CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE search_term COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

In the future, when you create tables in MySQL, be sure to [append `CHARACTER SET utf8` to the creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

```
CREATE TABLE search_term (
    search varchar(200) primary key,
    site varchar(500)
)
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE       utf8_bin;
```

Finally, so you don't have to do this for every table, you can [create the database with these defaults already in place](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html).

Here's a [good post on the Unicode gotchas in MySQL and their fixes](http://dev.hubspot.com/bid/7049/MySQL-and-Unicode-Three-Gotchas).

On the Perl side, be sure to `use utf8` so the strings you're passing to MySQL are encoded utf8.

Finally, according to the [DBD::mysql manual](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3amysql), you need to turn on UTF8 support when you connect, not after.  Would be nice if it issued a warning.

```
Additionally, turning on this flag tells MySQL that incoming data should be
treated as UTF-8. This will only take effect if used as part of the call to
connect(). If you turn the flag on after connecting, you will need to issue
the command SET NAMES utf8 to get the same effect.
```

Change your connect to this.

```
# I threw in RaiseError because its generally a good idea.
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1, RaiseError => 1 });
```

Comment: Hi Schwern, after altering table, i still get same error. I truncated table and tried to insert again but same primary key violation error.

Comment: Updated my answer with another issue in your code.  Making your stack respect Unicode is a PITA.

Comment: I have used $dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');, but still i tried your solution.
I am getting same error.

Comment: Does `show full columns from search_term` have `utf8_general_ci` for the Collation column in both rows?  Also, what version of DBI and DBD::mysql is this?

Comment: Yes, it has utf8_general_ci in both the columns. I am using DBD::mysql version 4.020 and DBI version 1.616.

Comment: Figured it out.  In MySQL it's default collation is *still* going to think habo and håbo are the same.  You need to switch it to `utf8_bin`.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome :), thanks a lot Schwern for your time and efforts. Appreciate your help :)